# Show that $\langle Ax_j - b,x\rangle = 0$ for every vector $ x \in x_0 + \mathcal H_j$ and hence that $Ax_j = b$ iff $\mathcal H_{j+1} = \mathcal H_j$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

**Question:** Show that $\langle Ax_j - b,x\rangle = 0$ for every vector $ x \in x_0 + \mathcal H_j$ and hence that,

$Ax_j = b$ **if and only if** $\mathcal H_{j+1} = \mathcal H_j.$

**Notes:** $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}, A \gt 0$, and $b \in \mathbb R^n$. And $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$.

$x_j \in \mathcal H_j = \operatorname{span}\{u, Au,...,A^{j-1}u\}$ and
$x_j = \alpha_1 u + \alpha_2 Au + ... + \alpha_j A^{j-1}u$

Also, $u = Ax_0 - b \neq 0$

I also tried to prove the $\leftarrow$ direction, but I failed to do so (before I edited this, so I deleted my approach).

So I managed to do one direction:
$ x \in x_0 + \mathcal H_j $ , $\phi(x_j) \le \phi(x)$. Thus,

$\frac{\phi(x_j + \epsilon x) - \phi(x_j)}{\epsilon} \ge 0, \epsilon \gt 0$.

$\lim \frac{\phi(x_j + \epsilon x) - \phi(x_j)}{\epsilon} = \langle grad\phi(x_j),x\rangle \ge 0$.

$\lim \frac{\phi(x_j + \epsilon x) - \phi(x_j)}{\epsilon} = \langle grad\phi(x_j),x\rangle \le 0$.

$\langle grad\phi(x_j),x\rangle = 0 \rightarrow \langle Ax_j-b,x\rangle = 0$.

Because $Ax_j - b \in \mathcal H_{j+1}$ and $x \in x_0 + \mathcal H_j, \langle Ax_j-b,x\rangle = 0$.

Then $Ax_j - b$ is perpendicular to $x_0 + \mathcal H_j$.

If $H_{j+1} = H_j \rightarrow x_0 + \mathcal H_{j+1} = x_0 + H_j \rightarrow \langle Ax_j-b,x\rangle = 0, \forall x \in x_0 + \mathcal H_{j+1} \rightarrow \langle Ax_j-b,x\rangle = 0 \rightarrow Ax_j = b.$

Comment: Instead of downvoting: Pls use $\langle$ "\langle", "\rangle" $\rangle$, and explain the notation you are using. As it stands your post is not clear.

Comment: @Hanno Hi Hanno, please take another look at my approach, the $H$ is the span that is written there. (:

Comment: I took another look, and I'm still puzzled: $A$ and $u$ are used but not given, a.s.o. You write 'Question', but there's none. Put yourself into the position of possible answer-writers and edit correspondingly.

Comment: What is $A$ and that is $u$? As written, the question has no meaning.

Comment: @Hanno You're right, I've edited the question.

Comment: @WillM. Hi Will, I've edited the question, would appreciate taking another look :)

Comment: Right now the question states $Ax_{0}=b$ and $u=Ax_{0}-b\neq 0$. One of these is wrong.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens Edited again :)